# Restful Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, restful

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com angular, java e restful jersey. Porém não consigo mostrar os dados do rest na view utilizando o angular. O máximo que consigo é gerar vários objetos para cada letra que contém no XML do rest e não o retorno dos dados em si. Já tentei diversas formar, buscadas na net, e as que consigo mostrar algo o retorno é o mesmo, objetos gerados a partir do que tem escrito no xml do rest. Alguém poderia dar uma luz? Seguem partes dos códigos.

Service.js

```
    angular.module('meusServicos', ['ngResource'])
.factory('recursoProduto', function($resource){ //retorna um objeto
    return $resource('rest/produtos/:produtoId', null,{
            update:{
                method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'}
            }
    });
})


.factory('ProdutoFactory', function ($resource) {
    console.log('entrou');

    return $resource('/listacarrinho/rest/produtos/', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: false,

        }
    });
})
```

Controller js

```
var app = angular.module('rest.controllers', []);
angular.module('listacompras').controller('ProdutosController',
    function($scope, recursoProduto,ProdutoFactory){

    $scope.produtos = [];
    $scope.filtro = '';
    $scope.mensagem='';

$scope.produtos = ProdutoFactory.get();
     console.log($scope.produtos)

//aqui já tentei substituir por query mas o angular da erro.
```

Onde irei mostrar os dados

```
<meu-painel class="col-md-2 animacao-painel" ng-repeat="produto in produtos | filter: filtro"
            titulo="{{produto.titulo}}">
                <meu-produto url="{{produto.url}}" titulo="{{produto.titulo}}" qtd="{{produto.qtd}}" valor="{{produto.valor}}" total="{{produto.total}}">
                </meu-produto>
                <a href="produtos/edit/{{produto.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Editar</a>

                <meu-botao-remover nome="Remover" acao="remover(produto)">
                </meu-botao-remover>
            </meu-painel> <!--final do panel-->
```

XML

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<produtoHTTPs>
<ProdutoHTTP>
<id>1</id>
<qtd>3</qtd>
<titulo>Teste</titulo>
<total>13.5</total>
<url>teste</url>
<valor>4.5</valor>
</ProdutoHTTP>
```

main

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="text-center">Lista de Compras</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- Caso false o ng-show="mensagem.length" nÃ£o mostrarÃ¡ mensagem (em caso de length for null)-->
            <p ng-show="mensagem.length" class="alert alert-info">{{mensagem}}</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <a href="produtos/new" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                            Adicionar Produto
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <input ng-model="filtro" ng-model-options="{debounce:500}" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite para filtrar seu produto"> <!-- debounce aplica um delay para aguardar a aplicaÃ§Ã£o do filtro -->   
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- end colunm-->
        </div> <!--end row-->

    <div class="panel-group" class="col-md-12"> 
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="text-center">Meu carrinho de compras</h2>
            </div>
            <meu-painel class="col-md-2 animacao-painel" ng-repeat="produto in produtos | filter: filtro"
            titulo="{{produto.titulo}}">
                <meu-produto url="{{produto.url}}" titulo="{{produto.titulo}}" qtd="{{produto.qtd}}" valor="{{produto.valor}}" total="{{produto.total}}">
                </meu-produto>
                <a href="produtos/edit/{{produto.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Editar</a>

                <meu-botao-remover nome="Remover" acao="remover(produto)">
                </meu-botao-remover>
            </meu-painel> <!--final do panel-->
</div>


</html>
```

Rest

```
package rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped;

import dao.ProdutoDAO;
import http.ProdutoHTTP;
import model.Produto;

/**
 * Essa classe vai expor os métodos para serem acessasdos via http
 * 
 * @Path - Caminho para a chamada da classe que vai representar o nosso serviço
 * */

@RequestScoped
//@ApplicationPath("/listacarrinho")
@Path("/produtos")
public class ProdutoController {



    private final  ProdutoDAO repository = new ProdutoDAO();

        /**
         * @Consumes - determina o formato dos dados que vamos postar
         * @Produces - determina o formato dos dados que vamos retornar
         * 
         * Esse método cadastra uma nova pessoa
         * */
        @POST   
        @Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        @Path("/new")
        public String Cadastrar(Produto produto){

            Produto entity = new Produto();

            try {

                //entity.setId(produto.getId());
                entity.setTitulo(produto.getTitulo());
                entity.setUrl(produto.getUrl());
                entity.setQtd(produto.getQtd());
                entity.setValor(produto.getValor());
                entity.setTotal(produto.getTotal());
                repository.adiciona(entity);

                return "Registro adicionado com sucesso!";

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return "Erro ao adicionar um registro " + e.getMessage();
            }

        }

        /**
         * Essse método altera uma pessoa já cadastrada
         * **/
        @PUT
        @Path("/edit/{id}")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String Update(Produto produto){

            Produto entity = new Produto();

            try {

                entity.setTitulo(produto.getTitulo());
                entity.setUrl(produto.getUrl());
                entity.setQtd(produto.getQtd());
                entity.setValor(produto.getValor());
                entity.setTotal(produto.getTotal());
                repository.atualiza(entity);

                return "Registro alterado com sucesso!";

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return "Erro ao alterar o registro " + e.getMessage();

            }

        }
        /**
         * Esse método lista todas pessoas cadastradas na base
         * */
        @GET
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})

        public List<ProdutoHTTP> TodosProdutos(){
            System.out.println("entrou no get");

            List<ProdutoHTTP> produtos =  new ArrayList<ProdutoHTTP>();

            List<Produto> listaProdutos = repository.listaTodos();

            for (Produto entity : listaProdutos) {

                produtos.add(new ProdutoHTTP(entity.getId(), entity.getTitulo(),entity.getUrl(),entity.getQtd(),
                        entity.getValor(),entity.getTotal()));
            }

            return produtos;
        }

        /**
         * Esse método busca uma pessoa cadastrada pelo código
         * */
        @GET
        @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        @Path("/{id}")
        public ProdutoHTTP buscaPorId(@PathParam("id") Integer id){

            Produto entity = repository.buscaPorId(id);

            if(entity != null)
                return new ProdutoHTTP(entity.getId(), entity.getTitulo(),entity.getUrl(),entity.getQtd(),
                        entity.getValor(),entity.getTotal());

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Excluindo uma pessoa pelo código
         * */
        @DELETE
        @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        @Path("/{id}")  
        public String Excluir(@PathParam("id") Integer id){

            try {

                repository.remove(id);

                return "Registro excluido com sucesso!";

            } catch (Exception e) {

                return "Erro ao excluir o registro! " + e.getMessage();
            }

        }


}
```

Alguém sabe pq não mostra o objeto com os dados corretos e sim gera um objeto para cada letra do xml? O que tem de errado no código?
Agradeço demais pela ajuda!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não consegue fazer um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que possamos achar um jeito de te ajudar? Que da forma como está seriam apenas chutes.

Comment: @Sorack vou tentar colocar mais partes do código para vê se ajuda. Porém eu tenho um painel que mostra o produto no index... esse painel se repete para quando adicionar um novo produto, o mesmo apareça também na index. Ocorre que quando estou fazendo a busca no banco (com restful) o painel é preenchido de produtos e quando verifico no console, cada produto corresponde a uma letra do xml do rest.

Comment: Ah tah cara, você tá recebendo um XML. JS trabalha com JSON, não com XML. Tem que converter

Comment: @Sorack eu achava que ao colocar a @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) na classe rest, não converte?

Comment: Cadê o resultado do console.log?

Comment: @Sorack  
é atribuído um produto no painel para cada letra do XML. Olha a resposta no console... "<" 1 : "?" 2 : "x" 3 : "m" 4 : "l" 5 : " " 6 : "v" ... e isso se repete para cada caracter do xml gerado do rest...gera 466 produtos no painel

Comment: Mexi na resposta. Veja se funciona

Comment: @Sorack Nada. Continua retornando os mesmo dados... verifiquei inclusive no console do navegador para vê se estava importando o script porém tá normal mas a resposta continua vindo o xml... =/ vou adicionar a imagem com o resultado no tópico

Comment: Bom então é seu serviço o problema

Comment: @Sorack mas seria o serviço js ou o algo na classe java do rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo requisição para um path que não existe `"/listacarrinho/rest/produtos/"`.

Coloca essa caminho assim `/rest/produtos/listacarrinho` e no metódo do serviço rest, acrescenta o `@Path("/listacarrinho")`.

No  `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})` deixa somente o `Application_json`, e tenta mudar o tipo de retorno para response. isso deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar essa linha:
`@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})`

do teu Rest por essa:

`@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`